# Rail mount for shotgun

Tags: shotguns

I'm trying to find a rail mount for a double barrel 12 gauge shotgun.

Please notice it isn't a dovetail rail, it has parallel sides. I've tried already a dovetail mount, but it gets loose when shooting.[image]

Could someone help to identify? Or to find an adapter?